# Probability that random pairs don't belong to a set

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Define $X(c) \subseteq [n]^2$ as  $X(c) =  \{(i,j) : i + j = c \text{ mod } n \wedge (i,j) \in B\}$ for some set of size $|B| = m$.

Suppose that I choose a random subset of $[n]$ of size $k$: $K = \{i_1, \ldots,i_k \}$. What is the probability that for all $i_j, i_l \in K$ it holds that $(i_j, i_l) \not\in X(c)$?

I expect ${k \choose 2}/n$ pairs $(i,j)$ such that $i+j = c \text{ mod }n$, and for each such a pair the probability that it is not in $X(c)$ is $(1-|B|/n)$. So, I think this probability should be roughly $(1-|B|/n)^{{k \choose 2}/n}$. 
But, the pairs are not independent. In particular, if $i + j = c \text{ mod } n $ then for every $l \neq i $, $l + j \neq c \text{ mod }n$. So in fact there are only $O(k)$ independent $(i,j)$, which means the probability is roughly $(1-|B|/n)^{O(k)/n}$.

I can't decide which of the arguments is correct.